# CABasicAnimation for shapes in cocos2D?

Tags: iphone, xcode, path, cocos2d-iphone, shapes

so here is my code :

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];

animation.duration = 2.0;

animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

animation.autoreverses = YES;

animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

animation.fromValue = (id)boxPath;

animation.toValue = (id)roundPath;


[shapeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animatePath"];
```

`
I use this code in a UIKIT app but now I would like to use it on cocos2D, is there a way to do it ? please :) sorry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: do you want just to create frame animation? if so, there is CCAnimate action in cocos2d. You can init CCAnimation object with your frames, set animation duration and than create CCAnimate action from this animation.

Comment: well here is a link of what I wanna do :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558245/add-animation-to-a-shape-in-cocos2d

Comment: just explain in words what do you want to do. maybe i'm just a newbie, but for example, i cannot see what did you do it the code in your linked above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to move one sprite to one location and back to place where you start???
If you want to do that this is some code :

```
id move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:time position:ccp(x,y)];

[sprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:move, [move reverse], nil]]];
```

Comment: An I what I really need to do